# Configuration for eclipse sonar plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, eclipse-luna

I successfully linked my project to my sonar server with the sonarqube eclipse plugin. I dispose of a configuration file I use with sonar-runner which is not at my project root.

How can I make the eclipse plugin use my configuration file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse plugin does not take into account configuration files. All the configuration of the project is retrieved from the server. What kind of specific configuration do you put in your configuration file aside from basic configuration (projectKey, projectName, projectVersion)?

Comment: The location of sources, binaries , tests and coverage reports

Comment: Regarding test and coverage reports, they're not taken into account by the SonarQube Eclipse Plugin. The plugin only logs issues. For sources and binaries, the info will be retrieved from your project configuration in Eclipse. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Working+with+SonarQube+in+Eclipse#WorkingwithSonarQubeinEclipse-FAQ in case they're not properly configured.